# How to get the date after 2 years starting from a particular datetime?

Tags: php

There is a datetime column in the MySql database, say `2022-11-25 11:15:49`. How can I get the date in 2 years after this date ? The times of the future date will be 23:59:59, but the duration is the most important which is 2 years.

Comment: Anything not working with `DateTime::modify`? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: SELECT DATE_ADD('2022-11-25 11:15:49', INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AS future_date; are you want this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP (as this was tagged) `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['datefield'] . ' +2 years'));`

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php.